# Sitecore Publishing Service not working

Tags: publishing, publishing-service

I setup Sitecore Publishing Service on my server correctly. It worked fine for week.
But it started throwing error whenever I try to publish any item

Error : Could not resolve stores: 'public' of type target

I checked publishing service logs and found below error

```
2019-07-04 06:23:44.830 -07:00 [Information] Service Version   : "3.1.44"
2019-07-04 06:23:44.859 -07:00 [Information] Environment type  : "Production"
2019-07-04 06:23:44.861 -07:00 [Information] Log Level Filter  : "Default" => Warning
2019-07-04 06:23:44.861 -07:00 [Information] Log Level Filter  : "Sitecore" => Information
2019-07-04 06:23:44.861 -07:00 [Information] Listening on      : "http://localhost:40582"
2019-07-04 06:23:44.861 -07:00 [Information] Instance name     : "85ac4a37-9ce8-4bbd-bbec-5d5520218c62"
2019-07-04 06:23:45.254 -07:00 [Information] Source registered : "Master" ("Master")
2019-07-04 06:23:45.254 -07:00 [Information] Target registered : "Public" ("Public")
2019-07-04 06:23:45.323 -07:00 [Information] Scheduled Task    : "PublishTask-d2aef83be20c49cab25b13e3695a7440"
2019-07-04 06:23:45.323 -07:00 [Information] Scheduled Task    : "PublishJobCleanupTask-6cde74f286cb4ed1ad7b851af35ccbba"
2019-07-04 06:23:45.324 -07:00 [Information] Scheduled Task    : "PublishOperationCleanupTask-8ebf9e001c2b429bb42bc7ac47586c94"
2019-07-04 06:23:45.333 -07:00 [Information] Starting Instance Activation monitor ("MultiInstanceActivationStrategy") on "85ac4a37-9ce8-4bbd-bbec-5d5520218c62"
2019-07-04 06:23:45.376 -07:00 [Information] Instance Enabled  : False ("85ac4a37-9ce8-4bbd-bbec-5d5520218c62")
2019-07-04 06:23:45.402 -07:00 [Information] Scheduler Status  : Stopped
```

Here I can Instance enabled is false when I first installed it then it was true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have a custom publishing target (`public`) that you are trying to publish to. First thing I would check is the casing of `public`. From the sparse logs you provided, it looks like there is a `Public` target configured but you may want to update your publishing target name in Sitecore to be `Public` instead of `public` as a first step.

You will want to make sure that the various configurations in `/config/sitecore/publishing/sc.publishing.xml` are updated accordingly to match *exactly* to what your custom publishing target is.

#### `Settings/Sitecore/Publishing/Services/DefaultConnectionFactory/Options/Connections`

Make sure you have a `<public>` node in this section of the XML and configured with the appropriate connection string. The name of the node needs to match the name of the publishing target in Sitecore.

#### `Settings/Sitecore/Publishing/Services/StoreFactory/Options/Stores/Targets`

There will also need to be a `<public>` node in this section as well with the `<ConnectionName>` node containing the value of the name of the node previously defined in `DefaultConnectionFactory`, which in this case is `public`.